# Using an Inno Setup code section, is it possible to get the current date in m-d-yyyy format, and put it into the registry during install?

Tags: scripting, pascal

In the registry section, I have a line which looks like this (identifying info removed).

```
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\MyProgram"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstalledDate"; ValueData: "{code:DateTime}"
```

In the code section, I have a function, like this.

```
function DateTime():
begin
  result := GetDateTimeString('m/d/yyyy', '-', ':');
end;
```

No matter what I change, it just won't compile. The compiler says:

Line 70:
Column 1:
Identifier expected.

Line 70 is the one which reads "begin".

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: A function needs a type identifier (after the colon) to denote what it returns,